# Attempting to return an ndb model as JSON throws: "...is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I am having trouble returning ndb models as JSON.

I have a Game class, as follows:

```
class Game(ndb.Model):
    gameID = ndb.StringProperty
    gameState = ndb.StringProperty
    playerOne = ndb.StringProperty
    playerTwo = ndb.StringProperty
    def toJSON(self):
        jsondata = {
            "gameID" : self.key.id(),
            "gameState" : self.gameState,
            "playerOne" : self.playerOne,
            "playerTwo" : self.playerTwo
        }
        return json.encode(jsondata)
```

This seems to work ok, and when creating and storing a model using the following code, it works (I think)

```
class gameHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    gameID = self.request.get("gameID")
    gameState = self.request.get("gameState")
    playerOne = self.request.get("playerOne")
    playerTwo = self.request.get("playerTwo")
    game = Game(id=gameID)
    game.gameState = gameState
    game.playerOne = playerOne
    game.playerTwo = playerTwo
    game.put()
    self.response.write(game.toJSON())
```

In this case, "self.response.write(game.toJSON())" outputs JSON formatted text as desired, for example:

```
 {"playerTwo":"AI","gameID":"Test2","playerOne":"Peter","gameState":"dog"}
```

However, in the following class, I am attempting to simply retrieve a game model as JSON, but it throws:

```
TypeError: <class 'google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.StringProperty'> is not JSON serializable
```

The code that throws the error:

```
class getGameHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    gameID = self.request.get("gameID")
    game = Game.get_by_id(gameID)
    self.response.write(game.toJSON())
```

I'm confused because both instances of "game.toJSON()" should give the same result no? Am I making some fundamental error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax, you need to declare your ndb properties like this

```
gameID = ndb.StringProperty()
gameState = ndb.StringProperty()
playerOne = ndb.StringProperty()
playerTwo = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed it, thankyou! I thought it was going to end up being something basic